# How to arrange objects in a straight line in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm making a chess board with three.js. I have all of the files rendering properly (stl loader) but I can't seem to make them load on the correct position. I am setting all the pieces in a straight line as far as I thought but they appear staggered.

here is my code:

```
function renderPiece(loader, piece, coor, color) {
  loader.load(piece, function(geometry) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:color})
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
    chessBoard.objects.push(mesh)
    // mesh.position.set(coor[0], coor[1], coor[2])
    mesh.position.x = coor[0]
    mesh.position.y = coor[1]
    mesh.position.z = coor[2]
    mesh.scale.set(0.75,0.75, 0.75);
    chessBoard.scene.add(mesh)
  })
}
```

and here are the fn calls with coordinates:

```
var oStlLoader = new THREE.STLLoader()

renderPiece(oStlLoader, pieces.rook, [0, 0, -210], 0x000000)
renderPiece(oStlLoader, pieces.bishop, [0, 0, -140], 0x000000)
renderPiece(oStlLoader, pieces.knight, [0, 0, -70], 0x000000)
renderPiece(oStlLoader, pieces.king, [0, 0, 0], 0x000000)
renderPiece(oStlLoader, pieces.queen, [0, 0, 70], 0x000000)
renderPiece(oStlLoader, pieces.knight, [0, 0, 140], 0x000000)
renderPiece(oStlLoader, pieces.bishop, [0, 0, 210], 0x000000)
renderPiece(oStlLoader, pieces.rook, [0, 0, 280], 0x000000)
```

Comment: Is the centerpoint of each model in the center of the chess piece?

Comment: Good call, it looks like files I used have a default position thats getting added to by my position setting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must create 3D models with a XYZ zero vector in the place, where should be center of your chess field.

After that, you can use more simple method to set correct positions, use predefined vector array for that:

```
var fields = [];
    fields['a1'] = new THREE.Vector3(10,0,10);
    fields['a2'] = new THREE.Vector3(10,0,20);
    fields['b1'] = new THREE.Vector3(20,0,10);
```

and then set a position of your model:

```
mymodel.position.set(fields['a2'].x,fields['a2'].y,fields['a2'].z);
//or
mymodel.position = new THREE.Vector3.copy(fields['a2']);
```